# Kotlin Android Navigation to Fragment don't work in setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, kotlin, listview

I am in a fragment with listview and a working `onItemClickListener`.

When I test the `onItemClickListener` e.g. by showing a toast everything works.

This is how my file looks like:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        with (binding) {
            val arrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<*>
            val employeeCategories = arrayOf(
                "Test", "Test2", "Test3"
            )

            arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(
                activity!!,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, employeeCategories)

            employeeListView.apply {
                adapter = arrayAdapter
            }


            employeeListView.setOnItemClickListener{parent, view, position, id ->
                if (position==0){
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Item One",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

To navigate from this fragment to another, I want to do the following when a List Item is clicked:

```
            activity!!.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).popBackStack()
            activity!!.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.navigation_help)
```

If I add this outside the `onItemClickListener`, it also navigates successfully. However, if I add the same in the `onItemClickListener`, at the place where the toast was before for testing, it does not work anymore. There is no navigation after I have clicked on an item:

```
            activity!!.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).popBackStack()
            activity!!.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.navigation_help)  <---- WORKS!

            employeeListView.setOnItemClickListener{parent, view, position, id ->
                if (position==0){
                    activity!!.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).popBackStack()
                    activity!!.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.navigation_help)  <---- DONT WORKS! :(              
                }
```

I am still relatively new to Kotlin and unfortunately cannot explain why this works outside of the `onItemClickListener` but not in combination with it. Can someone possibly tell me what this could be related to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add as a global variable (outside of your onViewCreated method) the following:

```
private val navController by lazy { findNavController() }
```

and afterwards do the this:

```
employeeListView.setOnItemClickListener{parent, view, position, id ->
                if (position==0){
                   navController.popBackStack()
                   navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_help)
                }
```

and let me know if it works now?

Comment: Yes, I could hardly believe my eyes but that actually worked. I really thank you so much for the help!
Honestly, but I understand the background yet not quite: Can you explain me maybe briefly in a few words why it works that way and not as I did it?

Comment: Glad to help you out. I think the problem is that you were retrieving the navController from the activity while you need it in the fragment. It might have also worked by using: 
findNavController() and the calling the navigation method popbackstack and navigate.